# Accessing a model method from a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have got a login form using the bcrypt gem. Its working as expected in the rails console. However, I get these errors on the site. Any help would be most appreciated.

> NoMethodError in ManagersController#loginattempt undefined method `authenticate' for true:TrueClass

I've read a few SO posts - I used, made revisions they do not resolve the error:

For example - it is because the authenticate class doesn't have 'self' prefixed, this suggestion actually breaks the working functionality in the terminal `@some_user.authenticate('***********') => true`

```
    def authenticate(password)
        self.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
or

    def self.authenticate(password)
        self.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end

or
    def self.authenticate(password)
        password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
```

Model

```
class Manager < ApplicationRecord
    attr_accessor :password

    validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
    validates :password, presence: true, on: :create


    before_validation(on: :create) do
        encrypt_password
    end

    def authenticate(password)
        password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end

    private 
        def encrypt_password
            self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
            self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
        end
end
```

Controller - which produces errors.

```
class ManagersController < ApplicationController
    ...
    def loginattempt
        @manager = Manager.where(manager_params).exists?
        if @manager && @manager.authenticate(manager_params)
            redirect_to managers_path, notice: 'You are logged in.'
        else  
            redirect_to manager_login_path, notice: 'Username or Password incorrect.'
        end   
    end

    private
        def manager_params
            params.require(:manager).permit(:username, :password)
        end
end
```

**For posterity
I believe this works now as expected** - thank you to the SO community for helping me in my hour of need. 
Working Controller

```
    def loginattempt
        @manager = Manager.find_by_username(manager_params[:username])
        if @manager.present? && @manager.authenticate(manager_params[:password])
            redirect_to manager_logged_in_path(@manager), notice: 'Logged In.'
            session[:logged_in] = @manager.id
        else  
            redirect_to manager_login_path, notice: 'Username or Password incorrect.'
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to note:

1. `Manager.where(manager_params)` is redundant because `manager_params` is something like `{manager: {username: 'foo', password: 'password'}}` but `where` methods takes simple hash like `{username: 'foo', password: 'password'}`.
2. You can and should use `find_by` instead of `where` and `exists?` because `exists?` returns Boolean and this is not what you want. `find_by` returns nil if the record doesn't exist.
3. `Manager#authenticate` method (`authenticate` instance method on `Manager` class) takes only password so you can use `@manager.authenticate(params[:manager][:password])` instead of `@manager.authenticate(manager_params)`

I'd like to mention that if `username` is unique we can find a user by `username` only, without password.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response (as was Sebastians) I realise I have a way to go on my Rails journey. Everything you wrote is really clear. I have tried your step 3, but get the following error "PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column managers.password does not exist LINE 1: ...M "managers" WHERE "managers"."username" = $1 AND "managers"... ^" do you know if it is because of attr_accessor?

Comment: Could you provide your implementation of `authenticate` method? Also, if you're doing something like `Manager.find_by({username: 'foo', password: 'password'})`, you probably cannot do that because `managers` table doesn't have `password` column.

Comment: thank you for your kind assistance. The tutorial I followed, creates a model with password_hash & password_salt. They use something called attr_accessor :password in the model. This creates a password field in my new.html.erb & create method. This works great. I am not sure to use the attr_accessor in the authenticate method. As it works in the terminal. Authenticate is in my original post as an FYI